# Multiple selects and comparisons in sql

Tags: sql, select, subquery

```
String sql = "
    SELECT NAME, 
           SURNAME, 
           ORDERID, 
           CUSTOMERID, 
           PRIORITY, 
           STATUS, 
           DATE, 
           TIME 
    FROM ORDERS O 
    WHERE O.CUSTOMERID IN "
            + "(SELECT LOGGEDIN 
                FROM CUSTOMERS 
                WHERE LOGGEDIN=1)";
```

I have two tables one called customer and one called orders. In my customer table I want to retrieve all the people who are currently logged in to the system and then match this with my orders table to see if they currently have any orders pending as well. Both of these tables contain a customerid column which contain the same values. However, I am not sure how to use and carry out the logged in check all in one statement. Above is one of the attempts that I have made which is currently incorrect as it needs to add a join for the customerid's but I am unsure who to carry this out. In addition, the sql driver that I am using is Apache Derby in case anyone was wondering

Comment: Does that not work? What DB is this in?

Comment: @BAReese In jdbc using the derby driver. When I run this query it gives me this error:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "FROM" at line 1, column 127.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like it's probably that extra comma. "FROM" isn't a column and even if it was the DB wouldn't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is fine but you need to select "CUSTOMERID" at the end

```
 ... IN (
 SELECT CUSTOMERID
 FROM CUSTOMERS 
 WHERE LOGGEDIN=1 )
```

But I recommend to user JOINS.
To see the users who have pending orders:

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM CUSTOMERS C
INNER JOIN ORDERS O 
ON O.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID
WHERE C.LOGGEDID = 1
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMERID
```

To see the pending orders by user:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS O
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C 
ON O.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID AND C.LOGGEDID = 1
```

Comment: I would *not* recommend using a `join` with a `group by`.  Use `in` or `exists`.

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it - at least one solution... I'm guessing you're getting an error though because you've get a rogue comma in your subquery:

```
String sql = "SELECT NAME, SURNAME, ORDERID, CUSTOMERID, PRIORITY, STATUS, DATE, TIME "
           +  "FROM ORDERS O WHERE O.CUSTOMERID IN (SELECT LOGGEDIN, FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE LOGGEDIN=1)";
```